# Xamarin Forms Catalog Thumbnail View

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have built a Xamarin Forms app for Android and iOS for the company that I work for.  This is my first exposure to Xamarin and while I really like the ability to write native apps for these platforms in C#, there are some details that I'm still working on.

One of the pages that I create is a thumbnail view of all products of a particular type.  I was creating the page by dynamically generating a Grid where I would create a stack panel with an image, price and name of the product, and insert it into the appropriate row/cell combination.  Problem is, on large catalogs, this would cause the page to crash because it is using too much memory with the Image control.  I solved this by using a WebView for the image/price/name combination, which works but I know is not the best way.

I've researched using bindings but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  I'm not using XAML but rather generating the UI dynamically from the code.  If anyone would be willing to give me a sample of how to do this the right way I would really appreciate it!!  There are a fair amount of examples out there, but I can't find anything on how to display essentially a gallery of products.

Comment: Are you just asking for an example of binding an Image?  That will probably not solve your memory issues.  Are your images full sized, or are they already scaled appropriately?  If they are full sized that is probably causing your memory problems.

Comment: @Jason thank you for your response.  My images are already scaled down and compressed as much as I can without losing quality.  They are pretty small now.  What I'm really looking for is an example of binding to a grid.  If I want a grid, 3 columns wide, as many rows as needed, populated from a SQL Lite database, what is the best way to do that.  I'm currently building it cell by cell, which I know isn't good.  Any help would be appreciated!!